# What makes you feel smarter after sprinting?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, intelligence, sport-psychology

**Background:** Every time I sprint, I feel smarter the day after.

Why would someone feel smarter after they have been sprinting?

Comment: I feel a similar sensation after exersizing in general. I think that it's a hormonal thing, perhaps more energy in general after physical performance.

Comment: Instead of assuming that it's true that people (in general) feel smarter after sprinting or exercising, it might be more productive to word the question as 'Do people feel smarter after exercising?'

Comment: Or: "Are people smarter after exercise?"